# How can I test TryPush with settings?

Tags: tdd, bdd, cqrs

I'm going to test next controller:

```
public ActionResult Approve(UpdateBalanceCommand input)
    {
        return TryPush(input, setting => setting.SuccessResult = () => Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home").SetHash(Url.Action("Index", "Payment"))));
    }
```

How can I test the fact that the command had been executed with necessary settings?

Sincerelly,
Anton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use like this

```
Establish establish = () =>
                          {
              command = Pleasure.Generator.Invent<UpdateBalanceCommand >();
              mockController = MockController<SomeController>
                                         .When();
                          };

Because of = () => { result = mockController.Original.Approve(command); };

It should_be_push = () => mockController.ShouldBePush(command);

It should_be_result = () => result.ShouldBeRedirect("your url");
```

Comment: Actually now you can use simple MVD instead of MVC controller. Url.Dispatcher().Push(new UpdateBalanceCommand())

Answer (score 3):

See working solution below

```
 Establish establish = () =>
                          {
                              _command = Pleasure.Generator.Invent<UpdateBalanceCommand>();
                              _paymentController = MockController<PaymentController>.When()
                                  .StubUrlAction("/")
                                  .StubUrlAction("/Payment");
                          };

    Because of = () => _result = _paymentController.Original.Approve(_command);

    It should_push_command = () => _paymentController.ShouldBePush(_command);

    It should_be_redirect = () => _result.ShouldBeRedirect("/#!Payment?");
```